# Не понимаю, как использовать yield в автотестах

Tags: python, pytest, yield

Изучаю автотестирование и возникла проблема. В одной статье написано, что "yield — это разделитель, все, что написано над ним, будет исполнено до теста, все, что ниже — после теста." и приведен пример написания фикстуры:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def get_driver(request):
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

yield без каких-либо переменных прописан.

В другом месте я увидела другой пример:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Здесь уже yield driver.

Я не понимаю, когда нужно указывать переменную, а когда нет.

Comment: @Nati, добавьте пожалуйста ссылку на статью для полноты понимания вопроса.

Comment: 1. https://tproger.ru/articles/pytest-fikstury-na-chelovecheskom/
2. https://habr.com/ru/post/472156/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*@Nati, спасибо что добавили ссылки, а вот звездочки в коде вопроса зря, я уже думал что-то упустил из Python смотря на запись `**yield driver**` поэтому их (звездочки) лучше убрать. `yield driver` — это все равно что `return driver` (очень грубо но суть такая же) т.е. иногда в функциях Вы пишите просто `return` а иногда `return value` тут тоже самое можно `yield`  а можно `yield driver`*

Приведу пример на основе документации (только упрощу и return заменю на yield):

`файл test_sample.py`

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_fruit():
    yield "apple"


@pytest.fixture
def fruit_basket(my_fruit):
    return ["banana", "apple"]


def test_my_fruit_in_basket(my_fruit, fruit_basket):
    assert my_fruit in fruit_basket
```

Тут мы проверяем наличия банана в нашей корзине.

```
$ pytest
========================= test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ...
collected 1 item                                                      

test_sample.py .                                                [100%]

========================== 1 passed in 0.01s ==========================
```

А теперь я верну просто yield без банана т.е. так:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fruit():
    yield
```

Результат:

```
$ pytest
========================= test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ...
collected 1 item                                                      

test_sample.py F                                                [100%]

============================== FAILURES ===============================
_______________________ test_my_fruit_in_basket _______________________

my_fruit = None, fruit_basket = ['banana', 'apple']

    def test_my_fruit_in_basket(my_fruit, fruit_basket):
>       assert my_fruit in fruit_basket
E       AssertionError: assert None in ['banana', 'apple']

test_sample.py:24: AssertionError
======================= short test summary info =======================
FAILED test_sample.py::test_my_fruit_in_basket - AssertionError: assert None in ['banana', 'apple']
========================== 1 failed in 0.05s ==========================
```

В данном случае мы видим упавшие тесты. Т.е. В общем случае вопрос не сильно связан с тестами, а больше с возвращаемым значением. Если нам где-то нужен `driver` мы его возвращаем, не нужен делаем просто `yield` отличие которого от return только лишь в том что при повторном запуске сработает не этот а следующий за ним `yield` если он есть, например так:

```
def my_fruit():
    yield 'apple'  # <--- вернет в первый раз
    yield 'kivi'   # <--- вернет во второй раз
```

Но конкретно в фикстурах `yield` должен быть один!

```
____________ ERROR at teardown of test_my_fruit_in_basket _____________
fixture function has more than one 'yield':

@pytest.fixture
def my_fruit():
    yield "apple"
    yield "kivi"
```

Это связано с освобождением ресурсов после выполнения кода, например: закрытие `driver`

Одним словом, не знаете возвращать или нет — **возвращайте**, много не потеряете.

Надеюсь, моих объяснений окажется достаточно, чтобы двигаться дальше.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Буду использовать совет про возврат.